# Android Studio Play Store Try Again

Tags: android, android-studio

i try to open the playstore in android studio emulator, but the playstore show try again, looks like it won't connect into playstore, i thought it was a network issue but i can use internet in the emulator, like using it for browsing the internet works, i already download google play service in os each and on SDK tools and already reopen the android studio, i use Tiramisu 13 as OS, what is the possible problem in this case ?

[image: Google Playstore show try again]

This is the picture of i already install the google play service
[image: Google Play Service installed]

This is the picture of i already install the google play service on Tiramisu OS
[image: Google Play service installed on Tiramisu OS]

Comment: Is your network can access google play store, open chrome type google play store web site check your network can accessable

Comment: yes i can access the google play store from the chrome inside the emulator